# Iphone and Android Number field with ":" and "." characters allowed?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, forms

I need to have a number field that allows for characters ":" and "." to be submitted. I need basically a text field that defaults to the alphnumeric keyboard for users since typically they will enter time "2" or "3.3" (sometimes they enter "1:30"). This is the code I did have but on some Android devices the webview messes up and people cant enter anything in the mobile_form_hours field. Anyone have any other ideas? I've tried keeping it a number field and changing it to a textfield before they submit the form, or mousedown on the submit button, but both of those dont work.

```
  <input type="text" id="mobile_form_hours" /> 

  $(document).on 'touchstart', '#mobile_form_hours', ->
    $(this).attr('type', 'number');

  $(document).on 'keydown blur', '#mobile_form_hours', ->
    $(this).attr('type', 'text');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) to set a regular expression of exactly what you want allowed.

```css
/* NOTE: This CSS is just for the live example and is not necessary,
   it's the HTML you want. */
input {width: 200px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #fff;}
input:valid {border-color: green; background: #eeffee;}
input:invalid {border-color: red; background: #ffeeee;}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="mobile_form_hours" pattern="\d{1,2}[\.:]\d{1,2}" placeholder="Enter a time, such as 3:45 or 2.5" required>
```

The pattern value in the example allows one-to-two digits, followed by a period or a colon, and followed by another one-to-two digits. If you just wanted to allow any series of number, periods and colons, you could use this value: `[\d:\.]+`

Note that however you enforce your value in the browser, you must also validate on the server.

Comment: When doing this, the alphanumeric keyboard does not appear in iOS. If I add that pattern to a number field, then the input value gets either deleted or validated and you cant submit the form

Answer (score 0):

You could split this into hours and minutes in 2 separate number fields, and use concatenation later. I don't think a number can have `:` in it...

```
<input type="number" id="mobile_form_hours" /> :
<input type="number" id="mobile_form_minutes" />
```

and when you need it in your code you could use:

```
var timeAsString = $('#mobile_form_hours').val() + ":" + $('#mobile_form_minutes').val();
```

this would give you more control over what your user's can enter, and reduce the risk of errors caused by entering words (there's always one user that tries to break everything)

Comment: Yea that could work, unfortunately this doesn't work for our designers... :(